# How to make an Ecommerce app in flutter with Backend?

Tags: flutter, dart, e-commerce

I'm trying to make an E-commerce app in flutter but I'm facing some difficulty in that app. I want to make two different apps example Admin & User. Admin Will Update Product Information like img, name, price etc & user will just Buy the product or Give Feedback for the Product. Anybody Know Any Resource Or tutorial, THanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: In Firebase backend, how to make Admin and Client eCommerce app in flutter

Comment: you can either make a single app and have two types of Roles for user and admin and based on credentials show them the content or have an separate app for admin and user.

Comment: Do you know how to implement Role Authentication in Firebase for flutter app?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. If you don't know how to use Flutter or Firebase at all, consider doing some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

just read the dart lang and GitHub has many projects which you can show and follow 
 [here](https://github.com/aviacommerce/flutter-ecommerce)

for the model, you have to use **build_value** [here](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)

fetching data, you can use **Dio** library [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Good Luck!!